# How to change label position in a customized twig form theme

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I try to override a symfony form theme. It works, that's the good news! 
But I'd like to change the position of the label inside.

My form Builder:

```
$builder->add('phone', IntegerType::class, [
        'label' => 'Telefonnummer',
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
        ],
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'input-field__input',
        ],
        'label_attr' => [
            'class' => 'input-field__label',
        ]
    ]);
```

My overridden integer_widget:

```
{% block integer_widget %}
<div class="input-field">
    {% set type = type|default('number') %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What I expected (shortened example):

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label>Telefonnummer</label>
    <input/>
</div>
```

What I got:

```
<label>Telefonnummer</label>
<div class="input-field">
    <input/>
</div>
```

The label comes before the div and isn't inside. But I need it inside!

What i tried (works but in my opinion it is a mess):

```
{% block integer_widget %}
<div class="input-field">
    {% block form_label %}
    {% endblock %}
    <label class="{{ label_attr.class }}">{{ label }}</label>
    {% set type = type|default('number') %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This way it looks like I expected. But it's just a workaround because i deleted the origin label by adding an empty 'form_label' block.

Is there a better solution to do this within the rules of symfony/twig?

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is this :

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="_input-a">Telefonnummer</label>
    <input id="_input-a" name="_name" value="_value">
</div>
```

Then there is no need to bother yourself with a custom `integer_widget`
Doing this instead is enough :

```
<div class="input-field">
    {{ form_label(form.phone) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.phone) }}
</div>
```

It will render what you want.

Comment: The phone input + label is only one part of a much bigger form and I'm a bit curious how to handle this within the form builder of symfony.